# Show the result of a fraction with e in the divisor as a graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I got some homework where I need to write a function which shows on the graph the function: 1/1+e^(-x).

So I succeeded showing the function as it should be written in the title, however when trying to define the variable (`f_x`) as the calculation it seems as I cannot put `e` in the denominator nor give it an exponent.

To simplify my question: I'd like `f_x` to show on the graph the function written in the title, in the given range (a and b).
How can I properly write the function into 'f_x'?

`f_x=1/(1+(math.frexp)**(-x))`   didnt't work

`f_x=1/(1+math.exp(-x))` niether

```
def plot_sigmoid(a,b):
    if a<b:
        style.use("seaborn")
        plt.title(r'$F(x)=(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x} )})$')
        x=np.arange(a,b+1,0.1)
        f_x=1/(1+math.exp(-x))
        plt.plot()
        plt.show()
    else:
        print("a should be smaller than b (a < b)")
        return

got me:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Tirgul/assign 5 plot-sci-num/Q2.py", line 16, in <module>
    plot_sigmoid(1,3)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Tirgul/assign 5 plot-sci-num/Q2.py", line 10, in plot_sigmoid
    f_x=1/(1+math.exp(-x))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: yet my question was not for you to solve my homework, only to help me putting the commands right,

Comment: So what is your current output with that code? Btw, please format your code nicely by indenting it with 4 spaces in your post, so that it appears readable for other viewers.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.
It appears that you need to go through the process of learning the language basics before you attack your homework.  Class materials and on-line tutorials should help.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully I gave enough info.
The main problem is that i don't know what I'm missing here... what is my mistake?
Thanks for the help and patience

Comment: Your title string `r'$F(x)=(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x} )})$'` has an unbalanced closed parenthesis and a possibly unnecessary pair of outer parentheses — I'd write `r'$\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for including the code in your question. The error tells you that `math.exp` can't perform vectorized operations. Since `x` is a NumPY array, you are trying to do a vectorized operation. It will work if you use a for loop and then apply `math.exp` on one element at a time. Other alternatives inlcude using `map`.

However, for the current problem, since you have already imported NumPy, you can use `np.exp` from NumPy module as following. Moreover, you also need to pass the x and y values to the plot command

```
def plot_sigmoid(a,b):
    if a<b:
        plt.title(r'$F(x)=(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x} )})$')
        x=np.arange(a,b+1,0.1)
        f_x=1/(1+np.exp(-x))
        plt.plot(x, f_x)
        plt.show()
    else:
        print("a should be smaller than b (a < b)")
        return

plot_sigmoid(0, 10)
```

[image]